# F# create random string of letters and numbers

Tags: f#

I have an issue with the below code. I am attempting to create a random string of letters and numbers. The below code works, however only creates 1 random string per session, so if I call the randomNum again it still hold the first random string created.

```
let randomNum(len : int) =

    let rand = new System.Random()
    let mutable str = ""
    let chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWUXYZ0123456789"
    let mutable count = 0

    for i in 1 .. len do
        count <- (rand.Next() % 36)

        str <- String.concat "" [str; chars.[count].ToString()]

    str
```

Does anyone know of an easy way to create a random string each time the randomNum is called.

Thanks

Comment: Alternative, simple solution:
let ranStr n : string = 
    let rand = new System.Random()
    new System.String(Array.init n (fun _ -> char (rand.Next(97,123))))

Answer (score 7):

You can do it using a more idiomatic syntax:

```
let randomStr = 
    let chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWUXYZ0123456789"
    let charsLen = chars.Length
    let random = System.Random()

    fun len -> 
        let randomChars = [|for i in 0..len -> chars.[random.Next(charsLen)]|]
        new System.String(randomChars)
```

We keep the `chars` array, it's length and the `Random` generator in a cloture and we return a function which takes the desired length to build the string from.

Calling the function:

```
let randomString10 = randomStr(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version which doesn't use mutability:

```
module String = 
   let ofChars arr = 
      arr |> Array.fold (fun acc elem -> sprintf "%s%c" acc elem) ""

let randomString len =

   let rand = new System.Random()
   let chars = Array.append [|'A'..'Z'|] [|'0'..'9'|] 
               |> String.ofChars

   Array.init len (fun _ -> chars.[rand.Next(chars.Length)])
   |> String.ofChars
```

(Performance could be improved further by not using sprintf in ofChars.)

Comment: Your `String.ofChars` function is unnecessary -- you can just use the [`String(char[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor instead.

Comment: Yeah, thx, spotted that but didn't have time to update.  I'd favour wrapping that constructor in the ofChars function to preserve ability to pipe into.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's the

```
new System.Random()
```

I have just moved it to the top of my code

```
let rand = new System.Random()

let randomNum(len : int) =

  let mutable str = ""
  let chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWUXYZ0123456789"
  let mutable count = 0

  for i in 1 .. len do
      count <- (rand.Next() % 36)

      str <- String.concat "" [str; chars.[count].ToString()]

  str
```

Comment: One self-answer is enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was calling the randomNum function from a different page and storing it as a variable

```
let randomtitlevertical = Functions.randomNum(10)
let randomtitlevaluevertical = randomtitlevertical
```

This only ran the randomNum function once per seassion. If I have the following instead

```
let randomtitlevertical = Functions.randomNum(10)
```

Then it will run the randomNum fucntion once per project.